# How to add leading zeros and commas to a number in PHP

Tags: php, integer, format, number-formatting

I have a variable `$counter` that returns the following integer:

```
4
```

I want to use number format or similar to make my integer appear in this format:

```
000,000,004
```

How can I this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) together like this:

```
$number = 4;
$formattedNumber = sprintf("%09d", $number);
$formattedNumber = str_split($formattedNumber, 3);
$formattedNumber = implode(",", $formattedNumber);
echo $formattedNumber;
```

## Edit:

Here is a killer variant of the above code that uses [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
function formatNumber($number, $desiredLength, $separatorLength) {
    $formattedNumber = str_pad($number, $desiredLength, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    while(strlen($formattedNumber) % $separatorLength){
        $formattedNumber = " " . $formattedNumber;
    }
    $formattedNumber = str_split($formattedNumber, $separatorLength);
    $formattedNumber = implode(",", $formattedNumber);
    return trim($formattedNumber);
}
echo formatNumber(         4, 9, 3); // 000,000,004   -- fixed width
echo formatNumber(4000000000, 9, 3); // 4,000,000,000 -- fixed width; overflow handled automatically
echo formatNumber(         4, 0, 3); // 4             -- no width specified
echo formatNumber(      4000, 0, 3); // 4,000         -- no width specified; comma added automatically
```

Comment: Does not work correctly for numbers bigger than `1000000000`. (Gives 100,000,000,0 instead of 1,000,000,000).

Comment: @Artefact2: see revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

One method you can do is [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf).

```
sprintf('%03d', $counter);
```

another is using [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
str_pad($counter, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function:

```
str_pad((4,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "4";
echo str_pad($string, 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // prints "000000004" (9-digit number)

/* 
   9 = How long the returned value should be. Must be bigger than length of $string
   0 = String to add
   STR_PAD_LEFT = On which side to add zeros? Left, in the case
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  [number_format](http://php.net/number_format)

```
$number = 1;
echo number_format($number / 1000, 3, ",", "."); // 2 decimals, "," and "." as seperators
// gives 0,001
```