# Fill the remainder of a string with blank spaces

Tags: php

I have a string with, for example, 32 characters. For first, i want to establish that the string have max 32 characters and i want add blank spaces if characters is only, for example, 9.

Example:

```
ABCDEFGHI ---> 9 characters
```

I want this:

```
ABCDEFGHI_______________________ ---> 9 characters + 23 blank spaces added automatically.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `str_pad`.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-pad.php

```
$str = 'ABCDEFGHI';
$longstr = str_pad($str, 32);
```

The default pad string already is blank spaces.

As your maximum length should be 32 and `str_pad` won't take any action when the string is longer than 32 characters you might want to shorten it down using `substr` then:

http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php

```
$result = substr($longstr, 0, 32);
```

This again won't take any action if your string is exactly 32 characters long, so you always end up with a 32 characters string in `$result` now.

Comment: Thank you all, this is complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_pad](http://php.net/str_pad):

```
str_pad('ABCDEFGHI', 32);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_pad` function:

```
$result = str_pad($input, 32, " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

you need `str_pad`

```
$padded = str_pad($in,32,' ');
```

You can have left or right padded, tons of options, check them all out [here](http://www.php.net/str_pad)

If the input exceeds 32 chars, no action is taken, but that's an easy check to implement:

```
if (strlen($padded) > 32)
{
    throw new Exception($padded.' is too long');//or some other action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more customization inside the function you could use this

```
function fill($input, $length, $filler = ' ')
{
    $len = strlen($input);
    $diff = $length - $len;

    if($diff > 0)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $diff; $i++)
        {
            $input = $input . $filler;
        }
    }
    return substr($input, 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for($i=0;$i<(32-strlen($your_string));$i++)
{ 
    $new_string.=$your_string.' '
}
```

hope that would be helpful for you

Comment: very good approach, but when there are built-in methods we shouldn't try custom designed logics.. i hope you got my point..

Answer (score -4):

```
$str = "ABCDEFGHI";
for ($i = 0; $i < 23; $i++) {
    $str .= "&nbsp;";
}
```

This is what You want?

When saw other comments, then that will be the best solution.