# PHP Generate Random Number Between 00 - 29

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php)

I have values between 00 - 29 that need to be selected randomly using PHP. 
I tried to use rand() function, but it gives me 0 - 29. not 00, 01, 02, 03 ... etc.

how to get 00 - 09 instead of 0 - 9 from PHP randomly? thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$random = sprintf("%02f", rand(0,29));
```

or, as mentioned in the comments:

```
$random = str_pad(rand(0,29), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: I would make that sprintf instead of spintf ;)

Comment: +1 Beat me. `str_pad()` is a good option too. Little less technical than `*printf()` in this case.

Comment: it gives me : 0.00, 1.00, 2.00... not 00, 01, 02... is there something missing here?

Comment: Updated the answer to also show `str_pad()` (good point Jason) and fixed the decimal bug

Comment: He had the wrong format for `sprintf()` see update. (told you it was technical :)

Comment: IT WORKS!! but, I have to wait for next 6 minutes to accept this as answer... LOL!

Answer (score 1):

Create an array like

```
$array = array('00','01','02','03'....,'29');
echo $array[array_rand($array)];
```

Comment: +1 For providing an alternative. Although quite an *ugly* solution :)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I agree. It is an ugly solution.

Comment: Yep, it will work, but just do not do like that:)

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
$random = str_pad(rand(0, 29), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

a) Add a "0" if the value ist below 10

b) Use number_format to process the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprintf to format the number.

```
$number = rand(0,29);
$number = sprintf("%02d", $number);
```

Search PHP manual for sprintf

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach that doesn't depend on additional functions:

```
$n = rand(0, 29);
if( $n < 10 ) $n = "0" . $n;
```

Comment: Yes this work. But silly when native functions exist. Why code around them? [Be a better PHP developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).