# PHP display 01 instead of 1

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php)

I am populating a select box with php.

This is the code:

```
$select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
$select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';
```

This is creating this:

```
<select id="month" name="month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option selected="selected" value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that I need the 1, 2, 3 etc to be 01, 02, 03 etc... Like this:

```
<option value="01">January</option>
```

instead of:

```
<option value="1">January</option>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know about [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)? Try echo `sprintf('%02d', 1);`

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php

Comment: You use tenary to display `selected`, it can be used for the option value as well: `( strlen($x)==1? '0'.$x: $x )`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

user `str_pad` ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

```
$select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
$select_month_control.= '<option value="'.str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. Double check next time you copy a line from somewhere ;)

Answer (score 29):

You can use `sprintf("%02d", $number)` to format strings.

Edit: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php for more information about format strings

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try using the [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function within your loop :

> **`str_pad`** — Pad a string to a certain length with another string

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
  $value = str_pad($x,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
```