# keep preceeding zeros when working with a integer

Tags: php

I'm using this code:

```
$start = substr($string, 0, -6);
$end = substr($string, -6);
for($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++) {
    if($end > 500) {
        echo $start.$end--."<br />";
    } else {
        echo $start.$end++."<br />";
    }
}
```

Where `$string` will something like `RXV123456` always last 6 characters will be a number.

If `$string` is `RXV123456`, the output will be someting like:

```
RXV123456
RXV123455
RXV123454
...
```

But, if `$string` will be something like `RXV012345`, I get this output:

```
RXV12345
RXV12344
RXV12343
```

Also if `$string` will be `RXV001234` or `RXV000123`, same thing, that zeros will be omitted.

Any ideas how to keep the zeros if $end will start with one ore more zeros?

Comment: Make sure it is a string. If you have to work with numbers then you will need to convert it.

Comment: Always remember to read the FAQ - especially the part where it tells you to look for where it's already been answered.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php

Comment: i searched, but didn't found that topic

Comment: I was searching for preceeding zeros, not leading zeros, my english isn't that good

Comment: @AdrianG leading zeroes and preceding zeroes in this case mean the same thing. zeroes that come before an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any programming language will truncate zeros on the left side of an integer. If you want them to display, you can use a function like [str_pad](http://www.php.net/str_pad) to add them when concatenating with the other string.