# How to keep leading zeros in PHP integer

Tags: php

I am working with an api and need to pass it the ClientID as an integer. The problem is that some of the ID's start with leading 0's. When I pass the integer to the API...PHP is cutting off the leading zero's which makes the ClientID inaccurate. I have tried passing the ID as a string to keep the zero's but the API expects an integer.

Example: ClientID = 00061423 when I pass it to the API it gets shortened to 61423 leading the request to fail because it can't find that client.

Is there a way to have PHP keep the leading zero's on integers?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php)

Comment: What API you are talking about? What is the interface it using? This string refusal story sounds strange to me

Comment: PHP doesn't do type-check; what technology does the API use?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, you were right. The docs say that it has to be of type (int) but when I just passed it a string it worked just fine. I guess I should have just tried the obvious first. BTW it is mindbodyonline API and it uses SOAP.

Comment: If the API genuinely both (a) expects an integer, and (b) expects it to have leading zeros, then the API is faulty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot keep leading zeros in *integer*. You can either keep them in a *string* or *add* at output time, using `sprintf()`, `str_pad()`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
str_pad($var, $numZeroesToAppend, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as a string; the zeros will be maintained.

Comment: He says above that he tried that and the API expects an int

Comment: PHP doesn't do type-check. That should work.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I just passed it a string and it worked. Docs were not accurate.

Comment: If an API considers `00061423` and `61423` differently, it's clearly not an integer! +1