# Problem with shopping cart adds same product multiple time

Tags: php, mysql, cart

I have php mysql shopping cart which works well, but problem is that if I add product which has code numbers only without any letter, product is added multiple time.
For example product code: K001 is working ok, but if product code is 001 without K I have same problem.

```
$cartArray = array(
$code=>array(
'name'=>$name,
'code'=>$code,
'price'=>$price,
'quantity'=>1,
'image'=>$image)
);

if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $cartArray;
$status = "<div class='box'>Product is added to your cart!</div>";
}else{
$array_keys = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
if(in_array($array_keys, $code)) {
$status = "<div class='box' style='color:red;'>
Product is already added to your cart!</div>";  
} else {
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = array_merge(
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"],
$cartArray
);
$status = "<div class='box'>Product is added to your cart!</div>";
}

}
}
?>
```

---

I added please take a look, but have same problem

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row['name'];
$code = strval($row['code']);
$price = $row['price'];
$image = $row['file_name'];

$cartArray = array(
$code=>array(
'name'=>$name,
'code'=>$code,
'price'=>$price,
'quantity'=>1,
'image'=>$image)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that PHP mostly converts numers automaticaly to floats or ints (depending on the numbers). Try converting the $code to string before sending.

**You can do this multiple ways:**

`$code = "$code";`
*But you can lose the leading zeros then*

`$code = strval($code);`
*If the code it's integer then you also will losse the leading zeros*

As you can see you can use multiple ways, but try not using leading zeros in PHP or add them later as in this solution:
[How to keep leading zeros in PHP integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148486/how-to-keep-leading-zeros-in-php-integer)

Comment: Also for example I'm trying with code: 1234 not using 0

Comment: I added the code you recommended but no result can you check?
  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name = $row['name'];
    $code = strval($row['code']);
    $price = $row['price'];
    $image = $row['file_name'];

    $cartArray = array(
    $code=>array(
    'name'=>$name,
    'code'=>$code,
'price'=>$price,
    'quantity'=>1,
    'image'=>$image)
    );