# How to add unique code with mask CN492B9ХХХХХХ

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need to add code to the database like this CN492B9ХХХХХХ where XXXXXX number that begins with 000000 and incremented by 1 for each data. 
This is my controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new DeliveyInfo;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['DeliveyInfo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['DeliveyInfo'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

I ad to the model

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
        $this->code = sprintf('CN492B9%06d', $this->id);
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

But there is no id number. Where can i get it for the new record?

Comment: I probably would not put it quite right. I need to create a field in a table that will be written in a unique code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. Have a simple [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column on your database table that provides the incrementing number, and then [format it in your front end code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php) so it looks how you need.

```
$formatted = sprintf('CN492B9%06d', $integer_from_database);
```

Comment: **+1**, Matt. It's the right way to do !