# PHP How do I format a number to show the hundreds as zero if the number is less than 100?

Tags: php, date, date-arithmetic

I'm calculating a countdown to a date. XXX Days Left. I'd like to show the hundreds place as zero if the total days left is less than 100.

This is where I'm at so far:

```
$now = time();
$your_date = strtotime(get_field('first_day'));
$datediff = abs($now - $your_date);
echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

Based on the target date, the output is 72. I'd like it to show 072.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Found the answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`str_pad()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
echo str_pad($value, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Or [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
echo sprintf("%03d", $value);
```

Comment: Thanks. I literally just found the exact answer on a similar question in the sidebar. Wound up using the sprintf() version.