# PHP Calculation with 0 in front of variable value

Tags: php, math

How to allow PHP calculation 0 appears if example :

```
$a = "00001";
$b = "00005";

$total = $a + $b;
```

Expected result is : `00006`

Including and keep `0000` appears.

I tried but the result always : `6`

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do normal math and then add the zeros back in front at the end:

```
$a = "00001";
$b = "00005";

$total = $a + $b;
$total = sprintf("%05d", $total );
```

or

```
$total = str_pad($total , 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try and prepend the needed 0's

```
<?php
$total = 6;
$total_padded = sprintf("%05s", $num);
echo $num_padded; // returns 00006
?>
```

I haven't tested it but it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?
   str_pad($num, 5 , '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
   str_pad($total, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the value is integer so you should use [intval](http://php.net/intval). If it is float use [floatval](http://php.net/floatval)

```
$a = "00001";
$b = "00005";

print intval($a);
print intval($b);
print intval($a)+intval($b);
```

than add the leading zeros