# How to convert a string of numbers in a number with the last two digits always decimal (though 00)

Tags: php, string, numbers

I have strings of numbers like this:

```
- 00986756849

- 007478599700

- 004583930237345
```

I need to convert these strings of numbers into new numbers with the last two decimal values in PHP, ie:

```
- 009867568.49

- 0074785997.00

- 0045839302373.45
```

How to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php)

Comment: @RuslanOstafiychuk His question isn't about leading zeroes, it's about 2 decimal digits.

Comment: you should explode the last two digits and then concate "." value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the string value . use  [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) to replace a sub string or insert a substring  to a specific position in the string :)

```
$str = "00986756849";

substr_replace($str,".",strlen($str)-2,0);
```

Comment: Also to say is that every number with a 0 at the start is interpreted as an octal number!(If you use it as a number) (Otherwise the solution is good :D)

Comment: @Rizier123 and how to fix this?

Comment: @JohnSam Just remove them. `$str = ltrim($str, "0");`

Comment: @Rizier123 there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
$intNumber = (int) $stringNumber;
$decimalNumber = sprintf('%02d', $intNumber);
```

Comment: You need to divide the number by 100.

Comment: Also, `(int)$stringNumber` will treat a number that starts with `0` as octal.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
//$str = "10";
$str = "00986756849";
$str_length = strlen($str);
if($str_length>2)
{
    $output = substr_replace($str,".",$str_length-2,0);
}
else
{
    $output = substr_replace($str,".00",$str_length,0);
}
echo $output;
```