# function argument value change when I add leading zero to number in php

Tags: php, function, arguments

```
function finderror($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
    ....
}

$arg1 = 054;
$arg2 = array('val1' => 12, 'val2' => 'T');
$arg3 = array('val1' => 12, 'val2' => 'T');

finderror($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

$arg2 and $arg3 are passed as arrays.
$arg1 is passed as a number. The problem is when I pass number with leading zero(054) instead of without leading zero(54), the number becomes 44 in the function. I want three number places. Whenever I add leading zero, number value change. How should I do??

Comment: 0 means octal sir :)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php

Answer (score 2):

If you precede an integer value with a 0 that indicates an octal (base 8) value. In this case 054 (an octal value) is the same as 44 (decimal). See the [PHP Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

It's unclear why you need to pass three digits to your function. You could pass a three-character string: `"054"`, or you could format the number for output in the function itself:

```
$arg = 54;
$output = sprintf('%03d', $arg); // "054"
```