# Adding leading zeros to number_format

Tags: php, numbers, number-formatting

i have problems adding a leading zero to a number_format() number:

```
$number = "6,0"; // coming as string from DB      
number_format((double)$number, 1, '', '')
```

I need to get

- 060 from 6,0 or
- 150 from 15,0 or
- 123 from 12,3 or
- 012 from 1,2

Using

```
sprintf("%02d",$...);
```

didn't help. Any other possibilities?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get rid of the commas first:

```
$number = str_replace( ',', '', $number );
```

Then you can use `str_pad` as was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php), which Francesco Malatesta posted as a comment.

```
$number = str_pad( $number, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

You can reduce it to a oneliner:

```
$number = str_pad( str_replace( ',', '', $number ), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace(",",'',$number);
```

use this