# How to always show less than 2 position int number using php?

Tags: php

How to always show less than 2 position int number using php ?

This below code

```
<?PHP
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
echo $i."<BR>";
}
?>
```

result will be like this

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
.
.
.
100
```

I want to always show less than 2 position int number. like this how can i apply my php code ?

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
.
.
.
100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure if this works, but you can try it like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    if($i < 10) {
        $i = "0$i";
        echo $i;
    }
    else {
        echo $i."<BR>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just paste the lines inside your loop

```
if ($i < 10) {
$i= str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

And print $i.

Comment: Awesome answer, did not know function `str_pad` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or the function [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) like this ...

```
<?PHP
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++)
    {
        echo sprintf('%02d', $i) . "<BR>";
    }
?>
```

... or this ...

```
<?PHP
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++)
    {
        echo str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<BR>";
    }
?>
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699980/5755166

Answer (score 1):

You could checkout the sprintf function that allows you to format the output http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Something like this perhaps

```
echo sprintf("%'.02d\n", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_pad` for adding 0's:

```
str_pad($var, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

The 0 will not be added if the length is greater or equal 2.