# Show Ordered Numerical Numbers of returned MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page where I want to display the PHP/MySQL results in a list, but I want to add a number before each title, like:

> 01 ... Title of the first article
>
> 02 ... Title of the second article

And these will be based on the number of results I get from the database. Here is my code to get the list:

```
ERROR
```

How do I get it to show `01, 02, 03, etc` in place of `$post_number`?

Comment: `$counter = 1;` Declare a starting variable (in this case, 1) and then for each loop through have it `$counter++` Use the counter variable in place of your $post_number.

Comment: Put `$post_counter++` outside of the variable string. It isn't HTML markup, it's PHP code. Also, put your `$post_counter = 1;` outside (and before) your loop.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to declare a counter variable so we can keep track of each loop through and print it. `$counter` is the variable I'm going to use in this example, and I declare it BEFORE the loop.

Replace your `$post_numbers` variable with the `$counter` variable, and INSIDE your loop, but at the END of it, we'll want to increment the `$counter` variable by 1. `$counter++` will increase after each loop through, so it will keep track of how many records there are.

```
    $posts_sql = "SELECT id, added, title FROM posts ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT $offset, $post_limit";
    $posts_res = mysqli_query($con, $posts_sql);
    $counter = 1;
    while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts_res)){

        $post_id = $post["id"];
        $post_added = $post["added"];
        $post_title = ucwords($post["title"]);

        $display_posts .= "

        <b>$counter</b> ... <strong class='resultsLink'>$post_title</strong>";

        $counter++;

    };
```

^For every loop through, it'll increment your counter variable by one AFTER it posts the current number. Since it will only loop while there are results, that will effectively count for you so you can number your list.

**EDIT**
As suggested by **CatalinB**:

```
<b>sprintf("%02d",$counter)</b> ... <strong class=\"resultsLink\">$post_title</strong> to show 01 02 03
```

This will allow you to have the preceding 0 in front of single-digit numbers.

Comment: <b>sprintf("%02d",$counter)</b> ... <strong class=\"resultsLink\">$post_title</strong>        to show 01 02 03

Comment: Thanks, but this just shows the number `1` before both of the results. It is also displaying `1++;` after each listed title

Comment: I just noticed that there wasn't an ending " in your $display_posts variable. Try it again. I'm pretty sure the lack of ending quotes was causing it to not increment the $counter variable as it should have since it was forcing it to be part of the string instead.

Comment: Actually that was an error on my part while copying and editing the code on here. The ending " does exist on my site code

Comment: Make sure you declare your `$post_counter = 1;` outside of the loop, and don't put the `$post_counter++` variable inside of the variable string. `$post_counter++;` is equiv to `$post_counter = $post_counter + 1;`

Comment: Thanks @Fata1Err0r. I had to change `$post_counter = 1` to `$post_counter = 0`, because it was showing the results as `2` and `3`, without the `1`. How can I make it `01`, `02`, `etc`?

Comment: Yea, that's why it's very important where you place your variables. You don't want it to increment prior to it executing your code. As for the `01` portion, I've updated that to my post. You're basically going to have it format it prior to displaying, which is what the `sprintf("%02d", $counter)` handles in the string.

Comment: Ok @Fata1Err0r. If I add my whole code could you show me where to place each variable?

Comment: @FootBlogger  I'd be happy to. I need to leave work and go home, so give me 40 mins though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php <-- Good link for preceding zeroes. Also, just make sure your `$variable++` is AFTER the variable that contains the string you display.

Comment: Thanks @Fata1Err0r. I've managed to get things working correctly so I'm going to leave things as they are now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_fetch_all` function to fetch all the record at once and then using `foreach` loop display all results and use key of $results table to display the numbers of rows.

```
$posts_sql = "SELECT id, added, title FROM posts ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT $offset, $post_limit";
$posts_res = mysqli_query($con, $posts_sql);

$results = mysqli_fetch_all($posts_res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $key=>$post){

    $post_id = $post["id"];
    $post_added = $post["added"];
    $post_title = ucwords($post["title"]);

    $display_posts .= "

    <b>".sprintf("%02d",$key)."</b> ... <strong class=\"resultsLink\">$post_title</strong>
};
```