# Why php array not support Zerofill arguments

Tags: php, arrays, zerofill

I have an php array having arguments with Zerofill values like..

```
$a = (00001, 00008, 00009, 00012);
```

When I am using this array as parameter of a function, then it giving  unexpected results, like...

```
print_r($a); //prints

array  ( [0]=>1  [1]=>0  [2]=>0  [3]=>1 )
```

Why? and how will we counter this error???

Comment: Use strings not intergers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) with leading zero are the [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) notation. If you need to prepend numbers by leading zeros you can [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php) string functions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$a = array('00001', '00008', '00009','00012');
```