# Codeigniter: Generate alphanumeric id

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to generate an id against a newly created user.

I want it to be something like this.

> Brb-0001 after first registration.

after 10th registration it should be something like this

> Brb-0010

And so on .

while searching I have come across various number generating functions but neither of these were helping me.

Comment: add code what you tried so far !!!

Comment: i have tried these functions so far.
  echo random_string('alnum',5);
  echo  rand(5,10);
         echo random_int(100, 999);

Comment: no rand will not works on here

Comment: what is this field name?

Comment: field name is barber_number

Comment: send DB reqest and get the las value of `barber_number` and add + 1 to that number add save it in new ...

Comment: [Use sprintf to format a zero filled fixed number string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1699980/3585500). `$myID = 'Brb-' . sprintf('%04d', 1);`

Comment: Not sure if this will help you https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/string_helper.html#increment_string

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong way. Use autoincrement integer field at database for this. Then you can always add `Brb-` prefix to this ID combined with some kind of `pad left` function (inside query or inside your PHP code).

Any other solutions may lead to race conditions. What if two users will register at the same time? I am pretty sure thay will have the same ID.