# How to format HH:MM:SS times if no leading zeros for hours, minutes , seconds php

Tags: php, formatting, timestamp

I have time string coming from an array and I want to add up leading zeros if it is not there for integer values below 10.
For example I want

```
this "8:10:12"  to "08:10:12"
this "13:7:14"  to "13:07:14"
this "13:25:6"  to "13:25:06"
```

I can go for a really messy code with splitting by ":" and so on, But I would like to know if this can be done with clean code by one line. Just reply if this cannot be done with single line. I'll do the messy code then.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Perhaps take a look at how the array is defined, and make sure they're in two digits there?

Comment: `coming from an array`=> so try to adjust array before it's coming finally to you in the given format

Comment: Thanks @AlivetoDie found the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use php date function `date` with `strtotime`

```
$str = "8:10:12";
$new_str = date("H:i:s",strtotime($str));
echo $new_str;
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/apIGj)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and it works perfectly..!

Comment: Glad to help @ShamithaSilva :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode`, `array_map`, `sprintf`, and `implode` to make it a one-liner, but it's not pretty.

```
$time = implode(':', array_map(function($num) { return sprintf("%02d", $num); }, explode(':', $time)));
```

See [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php) for other ways to format a number with leading zeroes.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Since that is a non standard time format you will have to parse it manually:

```
<?php
$data = ["8:10:12", "13:7:14", "13:25:6"];

array_walk($data, function(&$time) {
    preg_match('|^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$|', $time, $token);
    $time = (new DateTime())->setTime($token[1], $token[2], $token[3])->format("H:i:s");
});


print_r($data);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08:10:12
    [1] => 13:07:14
    [2] => 13:25:06
)
```