# Yii-2 Unable to format a number with leading zeros in PHP

Tags: php, yii2, numbers, format

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699980/8919244) solution. I am trying to format a number with leading zero's. The length is 12 digits. The starting is `00000000001` and if the number is 10 then `000000000010` and so on. **I have tried below**

```
 OGP-<?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0]; 
 str_pad($model['OGP_Serial_No'], 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)?>
```

But it's giving me empty result `OGP-`.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The result of the str_pad() is going nowhere. You need to save the result to a variable first or echo the result.

Comment: `OGP-<?php $model=$dataProvider->getModels()[0];$value = implode(',', $model); str_pad($value, 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)?` still giving empty result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
if(isset($dataProvider->getModels()[0]) && $dataProvider->getModels()[0] != array()){

    $model = $dataProvider->getModels()[0]; 
    $OGP_Serial_No = $model['OGP_Serial_No'];
    $myNumber = "OGP-".str_pad($OGP_Serial_No, 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

}else{
    $myNumber = "OGP-".str_pad(1, 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
echo $myNumber;
?>
```

Comment: Happy to help :) @MrFaisal

Answer (score 0):

Try check the real content eg: using var_dump()

```
<?php 
      $models = $dataProvider->getModels(); [0]; 
      $myString  = 'OGP-' . str_pad( $models[0]['OGP_Serial_No'] , 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
      var_dump($myString);
?>
```