# How to add a number with leading zeroes in php?

Tags: php

Okay so I am designing a tracking software for a company. I have almost completed my software and now I realised that Bank Cheque Numbers can contain leading zeroes.
Okay so for some function I need to add a certain number to this Cheque Number but I need to retain the leading zeroes.
For Ex,
0701 + 2 should give me 0703 instead of 703. Also the size of the Cheque Number is not fixed so that i can add remaining digits as zero.

Comment: If it has leading zeroes, it's **not** a number (database zero-fill notwithstanding)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php)

Comment: @CD001 I am saving it into Database as varchar.

Comment: So it's a string ... why are you trying to treat it as a number, when it isn't one?

Comment: @aquaballin it's not. i already checked that thread after which I posted this question

Comment: You really shouldn't need the leading zeros. The banks can figure out the details without them.

Comment: just make it a string

Comment: use strlen to get the original length, cast to a number, compute your sum and then use str_pad ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php ) to add your leading zeros

Comment: @crozet thanks for the answer I really appreciate it. Can you post it as answer so that I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get the length of your initial string, add your value and then use [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.str-pad.php) to add again your leading zeros

```
$initial = "0123";
$length = strlen($initial); // save the length
$result = $initial + 2; // add your value (result is 125)
$final = str_pad($result, $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // add the leading zeros to the initial length
echo $final; // will echo "0125"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "sprintf" to give a fixed length to a number. (with leading zeros)
Try below code

```
<?php
$value = 701 + 3; //do your calculation

$final_value = sprintf('%04d', $value); //give a fixed length to value 

echo $final_value;
```