# How to override/change the default removal of leading zeroes by PHP substr() function?

Tags: php, whitespace, substr, removing-whitespace

In PHP when we do a `substr()` such that the resultant string should be something like `0004`, PHP automatically removes the leading `0`s and just gives `4`.

I want to avoid this behavior. I want the leading zeroes to stay there. How can I enforce that?

Forexample the following snippet prints **`4`**.

```
echo substr("100041", 1, 4);
```

How can I force it to print **`0004`**?

Comment: What is your PHP version? Because it is running fine in PHP 7.2

Comment: *"PHP automatically removes the leading `0`s and just gives `4`."* -- no, it doesn't. Check it yourself: https://3v4l.org/F3DdR

Comment: @akshaypjoshi 7.2. This is weird.

Comment: Does this exact code omit the zeroes?  Just wondering if there's more code that impacts this, maybe something treating the value as an integer or something.

Comment: @BizzyBob The exact code is `$alpha = hexdec(substr($bravo, 6, 4));`. Yeah `hexdec()` is treating it as integer and yes I am printing after `hexdec()` is applied. Now what's the solution. How do I solve this? I need `0003` as a result

Comment: Could use `sprintf` or `str_pad`; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who said? Php doesn't remove 0 in string...

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer.  It doesn't help solve the problem the OP was having.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway create a own function..

```
<?php

function substring($data,$from,$length){

    $sub = "";
    $data = str_split($data);
    $i = 0;
    $l = 1;
    foreach($data as $letter){

        if($i >= $from && $l <= $length){

            $sub .= $letter;
            $l = $l+1;
        }

        $i = $i+1;
    }

    return $sub;
} 

echo substring("100041", 1, 4);

?>
```

Comment: Or use `sprintf('%08d', 100041);`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't:

```
var_dump(substr("100041", 1, 4));
```

```
string(4) "0004"
```

([online demo](https://ideone.com/R1sWSq))

As per [documentation](http://php.net/substr) this is a 100% string function. It doesn't handle numbers in any special way.