# How to add numeric value to value without adding or subtracting it in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I would like to post a value to my MySQL database in this format;

`01, 02, 03... 
011, 012, 013... 
0101, 0102, 0103,`
etc.

(with a `0` before each value).

If I do it like this `"01+1"` I (understandable) get the value 2 and not "02".
is there a default php function that let's me set the default amount of characters or is there an other option?

I'm using laravel combined with eloquent and some own functions like so;

```
$lastSKU = $data->GetData('get', 'products', 'filter')->max('SKU');
$newValue = $lastSKU+1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data type is the table column that is receiving this data please

Comment: it's a varchar, but i could set it to an integer

Comment: Then you need TEXT Concatenation `$newsku = "0" . $oldsku;`

Comment: just a quick suggestion, by using TEXT as datatype, when i retrieve the data with the 'max' SQL selector, the value to select isn't going higher as '09'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you won't know how the format will be, if there is always a 0 in front it is easy enough to do

```
$value = '0'. ( $value + 1 );
```

PHP will automatically convert it to a number between the brackets and by adding a string to it it will become a string again.

Now if you do not know the the length or the padding in advance but you do need to keep the current padding I would suggest something like

```
$value = str_pad(($value + 1), strlen($value), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Edit, [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) is a bit slow these days, [`sprintf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-6082) can do the same trick but much faster

```
$value = sprintf("%'.0" . strlen($value) . "d\n", ($value +1));
```

Comment: thanks! this is what i needed, i missed the brackets. if there also a option for a default length? like 00000001 (8 characters for example)

Comment: yes just replace `strlen($value)` with your default value

Comment: also make sure to accept the answer and not just upvote it.

Comment: fyi - I was curious about your claim that str_pad is slow so ran a quick benchmark using PHP 7.2.10.  Results consistently show str_pad outperforming sprintf and getting the job done in about 1/2 the time.  Granted I think this is really micro-optimizing since both functions were able to complete 1 million iterations in .1 and .2 seconds respectively.

Comment: @billynoah yeh i did the same a while back, but someone proved me wrong : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php#comment-76360104

Comment: yeh but what happens if you crank up the values ? https://3v4l.org/1GLFD