# Ho do I output integers with leading zeros in PHP?

Tags: php, pow

I need a little help with some PHP code.  I looked at the examples for doing this with JavaScript and used that as the basis for a PHP implementation.  Two issues I haven't be able to resolve.  I still get a leading 1 at the start of the string.  I also get fewer zeros than specified once the values have trailing zeros (i.e 10, 20, etc).

```
$num = 2;
$numZeros = 5;


function listRiskNumber($num, $numZeros) {
    $n = abs($num);
    $zeros = max(0, $numZeros - strlen(floor(json_encode($n))));
    $zeroString = substr((pow(10,$zeros)),0,5);
    if( $num < 0 ) {
        $zeroString = '-' + $zeroString;
    }

    return $zeroString + $n;
}

$row = listRiskNumber($num, $numZeros);
echo $row;
```

I want to turn the leading 1 into a zero, and ensure trailing zeros don't get cut off.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php helps, then it can be marked as duplicate.  Not sure as the code you show is a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: Nigel Ren and ehymel.  That's the ticket.  We can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Nigel,  This was derived from a Javascript I found searching for similar solutions here.

Comment: Nigel,  The max(0, ...) code was to determine the number of leading zeros to display based on the size of the $num variable.  $zeroString was supposed to create the formatted output based on the max output.  The $num less than zero deals with negative numbers if encountered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sprintf("%08d", $value);

Solved the problem. Thanks all for the quick answers.