# Integer value ignoring zeros and returning full number

Tags: php, numbers

I'm looking to create a [PHP Range loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

In a first and second number in the range, but have noticed the first number which is

> 00006

Is being rounded down / flattened to show "6".

So when I echo the first number value I get "6" back. I need it to be "00006"

Then the next number will need to be 00007 and so on, via the range loop.

My PHP code at present is :

```
$first_number = 00006;
$last_number = 11807;

foreach(range($first_number, $last_number) as $id)
{
  echo $id;
}
```

How do I go about making sure that the number has the previous 0's in it?

Comment: you need to use some format function when echoing `$id`, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php).

Comment: Cheers @DefinitelynotRafal it looks like the number range is within 5 of that pad length, so that will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using printf() function.
See the documentation : [printf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

First of all in PHP, a number starting with zero is treated as octal number, But I guess `range()` function converts it as decimal. So if you want to start it with `20`. Like `$first_number = 00020;` then the output will be start with `16` not `20`.
So, if you want the output starting with 0's, then you can do like this:

```
$first_number = 6;
$last_number = 11807;

foreach(range($first_number, $last_number) as $id)
{
  printf("%05d",$id);
}
```