# Change Woocommerce order number to specific number of digits

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, formatting, orders

I need to change the Woocommerce order number from 4 to 5 digits. I know I can a prefix or suffix with this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number', 1, 2);

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    $prefix = 'WC';
    $suffix = '-XY'; 
    return $prefix . $order->id . $suffix;
}
```

But how can I change the number of digits?

Comment: Some feed back on the answer below will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str_pad()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) PHP function as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'customize_order_number', 10, 2 );
function customize_order_number( $order_id, $order ) {
    $digits = 5;
    $prefix = '';
    $suffix = ''; 

    return $prefix . str_pad($order_id, $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . $suffix;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Formatting a number with leading zeros in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699958/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-php)

Comment: This works well and does exactly what I want.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Does this mean that order numbers will go from 00001 to 99999 or from 00001 to 0000099999? Meaning; are we extending the order number length or just adding 0:s in front of it? Thanks for helping me understand.