# When should you start using string replace over sprintf?

Tags: java, php, c++, printf

To start off, I may be using sprintf in the wrong manner.

I'm making a framework plugin that takes strings as configuration. The strings have things that need to be swapped out, for example, one string would be a path template:

```
[root]/[template_directory]/something/specific/[theme_name].htm
```

The example above is pretty specific and has a lot of variables to be swapped out.

For less variables, I've been doing it like so:

```
sprintf('%s/some/file/path/theme.htm',documentroot);
```

However, I'm wondering if sprintf might be more obscure to use for more variables.

In the first example, should I be using a string replace for each variable, or should I use sprintf? Or am I horribly using sprintf wrong?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386593/why-use-sprintf-function-in-php

Comment: You're using C++? Have you considered using stringstreams?

Comment: @Hurkyl This isn't really language specific; I'm doing the code in PHP, but sprintf and string replace are in several languages.

Comment: @Kyle: I misread the question. :(

Comment: I think it depends on the language you are using. In C you use snprintf()/strncat(), in C++ you use std::string/std::stringstream, in Java and php you use what is best there. So pick one language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use replace in std::string:

Please look at this examples:
http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/16972/1954

```
std::string phrase = "[root]/[template_directory]/something/specific/[theme_name].htm";
std::string sought = "[root]";
std::string replacement = "newROOT";

phrase.replace(phrase.find(sought), 
               sought.size(), 
               replacement);
```

Good luck!